# How does Mesa recycle graphic resources?

Tags: memory-leaks, opengl-es, egl, mesa, wayland

I have a system running on an Intel debug board with DRM and Mesa.

This graphic system use Wayland/Weston and Mesa.

And applications are developed with OpenGL ES 2.0.

Now, I find, sometimes, if the application crashed, the Weston will crashed too.

By checking the coredump of Weston, I can find some invalid memory address was used.

But when I run Weston with Valgrind, there is not any report for invalid memory access.

So, I am thinking about if there were some shared-memory leak by mesa when the client crash.

Means, for example, an application draw a buffer, and commit it to Weston, after that, the application crashed, and mesa recycled all the buffers alloced by this application. But, Weston do not know this, it used the committed buffer and crashed.

Will those things happen? And what could I do to survive from this?

```
Core was generated by `weston --config=/usr/lib/weston/weston.ini --backend=/usr/lib/weston/ias-backen'.
Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
#0  0x00007fec68911b09 in raise (sig=5) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pt-raise.c:36
36      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pt-raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fec68911b09 in raise (sig=5) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pt-raise.c:36
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007fec685904b8 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
#3  0x00007fec6859358a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#4  0x00007fec685ca90b in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fec686c68a0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#5  0x00007fec685d4896 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7fec686c2d31 "free(): invalid pointer", ptr=<optimized out>, ar_ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:5000
#6  0x00007fec685d507e in _int_free (av=0x7fec688fbb40 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3861
#7  0x00007fec655d320d in intel_miptree_release (mt=mt@entry=0x18884a8)
    at src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965/intel_mipmap_tree.c:1036
#8  0x00007fec655d32a7 in intel_miptree_reference (dst=0x18884a8, src=0x1870170)
    at src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965/intel_mipmap_tree.c:989
#9  0x00007fec655dc640 in intel_set_texture_image_mt (brw=brw@entry=0x7fec69a44040, image=image@entry=0x185c050, internal_format=<optimized out>, mt=<optimized out>)
    at src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965/intel_tex_image.c:180
#10 0x00007fec655dc952 in intel_image_target_texture_2d (ctx=<optimized out>, target=3553, texObj=0x1888080, texImage=0x185c050, image_handle=<optimized out>)
    at src/mesa/drivers/dri/i965/intel_tex_image.c:426
#11 0x00007fec653544ff in _mesa_EGLImageTargetTexture2DOES (target=3553, image=0x185fb60)
    at src/mesa/main/teximage.c:3194
#12 0x00007fec660a2d27 in gl_renderer_attach_egl (format=<optimized out>, buffer=0x1889130, es=<optimized out>) at ../src/gl-renderer.c:1450
#13 gl_renderer_attach (es=<optimized out>, buffer=0x1889130) at ../src/gl-renderer.c:1919
#14 0x000000000040fdb5 in weston_surface_attach (buffer=0x1889130, surface=0x13ad650) at ../src/compositor.c:2266
#15 weston_surface_commit_state (surface=surface@entry=0x13ad650, state=state@entry=0x13ad778) at ../src/compositor.c:3190
#16 0x000000000041036f in weston_surface_commit (surface=surface@entry=0x13ad650) at ../src/compositor.c:3262
#17 0x00000000004104c7 in surface_commit (client=<optimized out>, resource=<optimized out>) at ../src/compositor.c:3289
#18 0x00007fec6835ad04 in ffi_call_unix64 () from /usr/lib/libffi.so.6
#19 0x00007fec6835a7fa in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/libffi.so.6
#20 0x00007fec696ff7ba in wl_closure_invoke (closure=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>, target=0x13ad940, opcode=6, data=0x13acd70) at ../src/connection.c:935
#21 0x00007fec696fc517 in wl_client_connection_data (fd=<optimized out>, mask=<optimized out>, data=0x13acd70) at ../src/wayland-server.c:407
#22 0x00007fec696fdd32 in wl_event_loop_dispatch (loop=0x11a7460, timeout=timeout@entry=-1) at ../src/event-loop.c:423
#23 0x00007fec696fc6b5 in wl_display_run (display=display@entry=0x11a7380) at ../src/wayland-server.c:1281
#24 0x00000000004092d1 in main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>) at ../src/main.c:1049
(gdb)
```

Comment: Mesa is a library not a process.  So if the client process crashes Mesa cannot clean anything up.  The OS will clean things up for the client.  Shared memory is a little more complicated.  The OS won't automatically do anything with shared memory because it knows that it is still in use (assuming shared memory is being used).  Focus on why the client crashed.  It is very possible to crash the client and the server if the client passes garbage pointers through OpenGL calls or otherwise corrupts process memory.  If everything crashes you need something to perform an automatic restart.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for your reply. So if the weston received the buffer-commited-signal, but have not start to use it. The OS might think there is only one process use the shared memory, and recycles it? And for the automatic restart , you means to restart the weston(server) ? Yes, I will restart it, but non-crash is better :)